# Why is this date_diff not working?

Tags: php, datediff

I want to display a 'NEW' div when an image has a 'date created' value set in a database, that is no more than a week old.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$then = new DateTime($imageSet->created);
$diff = date_diff($now,$then);
if($diff->format('%d') >= 0 && $diff->format('%d') < 8 && $imageSet->created != null) { $new = 1; } else { $new = 0; }
```

But with an image that has a date created value of 2016-05-17, this is showing the div 'NEW', when it's obviously much more than a week old. Based on my condition above, I'm expecting any date created value of 2016-07-12 or later to trigger the 'NEW' div.

Any ideas why it's not?

Answer (score 1):

`%d` is the *days* part of a *"years, months, days"* description. In the case of a 40 day total difference, say, it would be around 9 days, because it's a *one month, nine days* difference.

If you want the *total* day difference, use `%a`.

Comment: Ah I see. That would make sense, so it's only been counting the difference between the day value, regardless of any months.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
$now = new DateTime();
if(empty($imageSet->created)) {
    $new = 0
} else {
    $then = new DateTime($imageSet->created);
    $diff = date_diff($now,$then);
    if($diff->format('%a') >= 0 && $diff->format('%a') < 8 ) { 
        $new = 1; 
    } else { 
        $new = 0; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why

Comment: Because %d is for date in the month not for day of the year.

To compare two dates like this %a is the way to go 

php > $old = new DateTime('2016-03-04');
php > $new = new DateTime('2016-04-05');
php > $diff = date_diff($old, $new);
php > echo $diff->format('z')."\n";
z
php > echo $diff->format('%a')."\n";
32
php > echo $diff->format('%d')."\n";
1

Comment: What's with the weird characters in your example? And can you please outline why your answer is better or different than the first answer given?

Comment: Those are not weird characters, those are the things those appear when you use php cli by php -a 

And my answer is same as first one, It's just that the first answer was not there when I started writing answer for your question (left window open for some other task),  If it makes you feel better 'Sorry for answering'

Comment: There's no need to be like that, but you need to understand how this website works. There's no point placing the same answer as someone else if there's nothing different, it doesn't bring anything new. You should just do some 'spring cleaning'.

Comment: I get your point And as I mentioned above when I opened your question to answer there was no answer to it. Than due to some reasons my answer get delayed, Hence the duplication